# Graphic Usage Using PHP (Creating Bar Chart with Data from Database)

Tags: php, mysql, database, graphics

My assignment is to create the graph with data from database. I have done the following PHP code with given information.

```
<?php
# ------- The graph values in the form of associative array
$values1 = array (
    "Shopping" => 8491,
    "Transport" => 8098,
    "Food & beverages" => 7975,
    "Accommodation" => 6130,
    "Expenditure" => 894,
    "Others" => 2667
);

$values2 = array (
    "Shopping" => 13149,
    "Transport" => 10019,
    "Food & beverages" => 9691,
    "Accommodation" => 5028,
    "Expenditure" => 1097,
    "Others" => 3362
);


$img_width = 450;
$img_height = 300; 
$margins = 20;


# ---- Find the size of graph by substracting the size of borders
$graph_width = $img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height = $img_height - $margins * 2; 
$img = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);


$bar_width = 20;
$total_bars = count($values1 + $values2);
$gap = ($graph_width - $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars + 1);


# -------  Define Colors ----------------
$bar_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 64, 128);
$bar_color2 = imagecolorallocate($img, 100, 64, 128);
$label_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 240, 240, 255);
$border_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 200, 200, 200);
$line_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 220, 220, 220);

# ------ Create the border around the graph ------

imagefilledrectangle($img, -10, 1, $img_width + 8, $img_height - 2, $border_color);
imagefilledrectangle($img, $margins, $margins, $img_width - 1 - $margins, $img_height - 1 - $margins, $background_color);


# ------- Max value is required to adjust the scale -------
$max_value = max($values2);
$ratio = $graph_height / $max_value;


# -------- Create scale and draw horizontal lines  --------
$horizontal_lines = 20;
$horizontal_gap = $graph_height / $horizontal_lines;

for($i = 1; $i <= $horizontal_lines; $i++) {
    $y = $img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;
    imageline($img, $margins, $y, $img_width - $margins, $y, $line_color);
    $v = intval($horizontal_gap * $i / $ratio);
    imagestring($img, 0, 0, $y - 5, $v, $bar_color);
}


# ----------- Draw the bars here ------
for($i = 0; $i < $total_bars; $i++) { 
    # ------ Extract key and value pair from the current pointer position
    list($key, $value) = each($values1); 
    $x1 = $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap + $bar_width) ;
    $x2 = $x1 + $bar_width; 
    $y1 = $margins + $graph_height - intval($value * $ratio) ;
    $y2 = $img_height - $margins;
    imagestring($img, 0, $x1 + 1, $y1 - 10, $value, $bar_color);
    imagestring($img, 0, $x1 + 1, $img_height - 15, $key, $label_color);        
    imagefilledrectangle($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $bar_color);
}

for($i = 0; $i < $total_bars; $i++) { 
    # ------ Extract key and value pair from the current pointer position
    list($key, $value) = each($values2); 
    $x1 = ($margins + $gap + $i * ($gap + $bar_width)) + 22 ;
    $x2 = $x1 + $bar_width; 
    $y1 = $margins + $graph_height - intval($value * $ratio) ;
    $y2 = $img_height - $margins;
    imagestring($img, 0, $x1 + 1, $y1 - 10, $value, $bar_color2);
    imagefilledrectangle($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $bar_color2);
}

header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
```

It does not work when I try to replace the given information to the following code.

```
include('conn.php');

# ------- The graph values in the form of associative array
$values1_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM domestic_visitors WHERE year = 2010");
if(!$values1_query) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($values1_query)) {
    $values1_array = array($row["component"] => $row["total"]);
}
```

Having been trying for days but I just dunno what the error is.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the bottom section has these problems:

1. If the code is exactly as you have shown, then the `$values1_array` is not the same variable name as `$values1` which means that your bar chart drawing code doesn't know where to get the data from.
2. When you retrieve data from the SQL database as you have done, for each loop iteration, the line `$row = mysql_fetch_array($values1_query)` means that the variable `$row` contains an array of the data in that row, and that one row only! More on this below.

**Processing the data (properly)**

For the code that you are using to create the bar chart, the

```
$values1 = array (
    "Shopping" => 8491,
    "Transport" => 8098,
    "Food & beverages" => 7975,
    "Accommodation" => 6130,
    "Expenditure" => 894,
    "Others" => 2667
);
```

is what is known as an associative array. This means it is an array where the key/index is a name! (It is more like a Map or Dictionary in other programming languages). Whereas, the code at the bottom doesn't build this array correctly.

So for example, if your table is something like this:

```
+---------+-----+----+
|component|total|year|
+---------+-----+----+
|Texas    |200  |2010|
+---------+-----+----+
|Georgia  |300  |2010|
+---------+-----+----+
```

Then, the first time the code in the loop is run, the $row variable will be

```
$row = array (
    "component" => "Texas",
    "total" => 200,
    "year" => 2010
);
```

and on the second time, the $row variable will be

```
$row = array (
    "component" => "Georgia",
    "total" => 300,
    "year" => 2010
);
```

Notice that since you write `$values1_array = array($row["component"] => $row["total"]);`, the data in `$values1_array` is being overwritten for every loop iteration! Meaning that after the while loop is executed, you get the equivalent of:

```
$values1_array = array (
    "Georgia" => 300
)
```

and you have lost all the data in the previous rows.

What I am guessing you probably want to do (you didn't mention what is the expected output) is to append/add the data from each row into the `$values1` array. Here's one way to do it:

```
$values1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($values1_query)) {
    $component = $row["component"];
    $total = $row["total"];

    $values1[$component] = $total;

    // This can be shortened into:
    // $values1[$row["component"]] = $row["total"];
}
```

Basically, this code initializes $values1 into an empty array. For each loop iteration, we insert a new entry into the array, such that the entry's key is `component`, and the entry's value is `total`.

In this way, using the same example above, before the while loop, `$values1` is an empty array. After the first iteration,

```
$values1 = array (
    "Texas" => 200
)
```

After the second iteration, the next row of data is added, and

```
$values1 = array (
    "Texas" => 200,
    "Georgia" => 300
)
```

**Print your variables as a debugging technique**

Not sure if you already know this, but it can often be helpful to print the contents of your variables if you are having problems. Then you can check if the variables contain the data that you expect. For example, in this case printing the contents of `$values1_array` (or `$values1`, whichever is supposed to be correct) will show you that the array only has the data from the last row of the data returned from the SQL query. Some useful functions that you can use are `print_r` and `var_dump` that show you more information beyond the simple `echo` (see the PHP manual for information on how to use these functions), and you can use them to see the contents of arrays.

Comment: Tried your code, it does not work. The graph still not showing up. The expected output is like this -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4evf35NA5_5NG8zM2hUY2tRREk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The code in your question (the first box) already generates the expected output as you have posted, when I tried. So it already satisfies the expected output! What is the problem you are facing then? As I understand, you have already written the code to draw the chart (as in the first box, which works), and you are now having problems using the data from a MySQL table and putting that data into the bar chart, which was what I was trying to answer.